# How to calculate scheduled mortgage payment of a mortgage pass-through security?

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, mbs

I am trying to estimate the cash flows of Mortgage Backed Security.
The example is present in the Fixed Income textbook written by Fabozzi.

The problem and the solution is as follows:-

Suppose there is a **$400 million** mortgage pass-through security with a **7.5%** pass-through rate, a weighted average coupon of **8.125%** and a weighted average maturity of **357** months, how to compute the cash flows for the next two months assuming a **100** Principal Securities Association(PSA)?

[image: Solution for cash flows]

I have understood the values for all the columns except for **column 5**. Could anyone how did the value of **$2,975,868** come up in the scheduled mortgage payment for **month 1**?

Even the text book does not provide any references with respect to this.

Comment: Please click on the image to have a large view.

Comment: Try excel PMT function: PMT(8.125%/12,357, -400m,,0).

Comment: @Magicisinthechain it is working in excel. Any idea how to compute it manually?

Comment: Here goes: $\mathrm{pmt}=\frac{r}{12} \frac{\mathrm{PV}}{1-\left(1+\frac{r}{12}\right)^{-n}}$

Comment: @Magicisinthechain In the denominator, (1+(r/12))^n is greater than 1. So 1 minus that will result in a negative number.

Comment: It is minus n: 1−(1+0.08125÷12)^−357=0.91

Answer (score 2):

As per the answer by Magic is in the chain, this is just the calculation for the standard payment on a level-payment MBS pool with monthly amortization. If $B$ is the balance, $WAC$ is the gross weighted-average coupon (in percent), and $R$ is the remaining term (in months), set $G = WAC/12$ and $U = 1/(1+G)$. The monthly payment is then given by:

$PMT = \frac{B * G}{1-U^R}$

The standard payment keeps changing from month to month because (a) a 30-year MBS pool can have loans with a range of terms in it and the average remaining term of the pool may change as some of these loans exit the pool, and (b) Mortgagors often send in a little more than their scheduled monthly payments and these so-called curtailments act to effectively lower the remaining term of the mortgage.

For details, see "Guide to Mortgage-backed Securities" by Lakhbir Hayre et al.